# DBus: Autogenerated code with dbus-binding-tool don't work

Tags: glib, dbus

Edited: Include the srv_hallo function before the glue code. Is that correct? Now I can compile.

I'm new to dbus and I want to establish a communication between two applications (IPC) with the help of glib and dbus.

But when I want to compile it, I get the error from the auto generated code:

```
In file included from main.c:2:0:
test_example_Server.h:111:17: error: ‘srv_hallo’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   { (GCallback) srv_hallo, dbus_glib_marshal_srv_BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER, 0 },
```

What can I do there? Because this is auto generated code I don't know how I could solve this.
I hope you can help me.

Here is what I've done so far:

I used the dbus-binding-tool to autogenerate the glue code with the command:

```
dbus-binding-tool --mode=glib-server --output=test_example_Server.h --prefix=srv test.example.xml
```

The test.example.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<node name="/test/example">
    <interface name="test.example">
        <method name="Hallo">
            <arg type="s" name="name" direction="in" />
            <annotation name="org.freedesktop.DBus.GLib.NoReply" value="yes"/>
        </method>
    </interface>
</node>
```

The generated code (test_example_server.h):

```
/* Generated by dbus-binding-tool; do not edit! */


#ifndef __dbus_glib_marshal_srv_MARSHAL_H__
#define __dbus_glib_marshal_srv_MARSHAL_H__

#include    <glib-object.h>

G_BEGIN_DECLS

#ifdef G_ENABLE_DEBUG
#define g_marshal_value_peek_boolean(v)  g_value_get_boolean (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_char(v)     g_value_get_schar (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_uchar(v)    g_value_get_uchar (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_int(v)      g_value_get_int (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_uint(v)     g_value_get_uint (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_long(v)     g_value_get_long (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_ulong(v)    g_value_get_ulong (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_int64(v)    g_value_get_int64 (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_uint64(v)   g_value_get_uint64 (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_enum(v)     g_value_get_enum (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_flags(v)    g_value_get_flags (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_float(v)    g_value_get_float (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_double(v)   g_value_get_double (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_string(v)   (char*) g_value_get_string (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_param(v)    g_value_get_param (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_boxed(v)    g_value_get_boxed (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_pointer(v)  g_value_get_pointer (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_object(v)   g_value_get_object (v)
#define g_marshal_value_peek_variant(v)  g_value_get_variant (v)
#else /* !G_ENABLE_DEBUG */
/* WARNING: This code accesses GValues directly, which is UNSUPPORTED API.
 *          Do not access GValues directly in your code. Instead, use the
 *          g_value_get_*() functions
 */
#define g_marshal_value_peek_boolean(v)  (v)->data[0].v_int
#define g_marshal_value_peek_char(v)     (v)->data[0].v_int
#define g_marshal_value_peek_uchar(v)    (v)->data[0].v_uint
#define g_marshal_value_peek_int(v)      (v)->data[0].v_int
#define g_marshal_value_peek_uint(v)     (v)->data[0].v_uint
#define g_marshal_value_peek_long(v)     (v)->data[0].v_long
#define g_marshal_value_peek_ulong(v)    (v)->data[0].v_ulong
#define g_marshal_value_peek_int64(v)    (v)->data[0].v_int64
#define g_marshal_value_peek_uint64(v)   (v)->data[0].v_uint64
#define g_marshal_value_peek_enum(v)     (v)->data[0].v_long
#define g_marshal_value_peek_flags(v)    (v)->data[0].v_ulong
#define g_marshal_value_peek_float(v)    (v)->data[0].v_float
#define g_marshal_value_peek_double(v)   (v)->data[0].v_double
#define g_marshal_value_peek_string(v)   (v)->data[0].v_pointer
#define g_marshal_value_peek_param(v)    (v)->data[0].v_pointer
#define g_marshal_value_peek_boxed(v)    (v)->data[0].v_pointer
#define g_marshal_value_peek_pointer(v)  (v)->data[0].v_pointer
#define g_marshal_value_peek_object(v)   (v)->data[0].v_pointer
#define g_marshal_value_peek_variant(v)  (v)->data[0].v_pointer
#endif /* !G_ENABLE_DEBUG */


/* BOOLEAN:STRING,POINTER */
extern void dbus_glib_marshal_srv_BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER (GClosure     *closure,
                                                           GValue       *return_value,
                                                           guint         n_param_values,
                                                           const GValue *param_values,
                                                           gpointer      invocation_hint,
                                                           gpointer      marshal_data);
void
dbus_glib_marshal_srv_BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER (GClosure     *closure,
                                               GValue       *return_value G_GNUC_UNUSED,
                                               guint         n_param_values,
                                               const GValue *param_values,
                                               gpointer      invocation_hint G_GNUC_UNUSED,
                                               gpointer      marshal_data)
{
  typedef gboolean (*GMarshalFunc_BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER) (gpointer     data1,
                                                            gpointer     arg_1,
                                                            gpointer     arg_2,
                                                            gpointer     data2);
  register GMarshalFunc_BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER callback;
  register GCClosure *cc = (GCClosure*) closure;
  register gpointer data1, data2;
  gboolean v_return;

  g_return_if_fail (return_value != NULL);
  g_return_if_fail (n_param_values == 3);

  if (G_CCLOSURE_SWAP_DATA (closure))
    {
      data1 = closure->data;
      data2 = g_value_peek_pointer (param_values + 0);
    }
  else
    {
      data1 = g_value_peek_pointer (param_values + 0);
      data2 = closure->data;
    }
  callback = (GMarshalFunc_BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER) (marshal_data ? marshal_data : cc->callback);

  v_return = callback (data1,
                       g_marshal_value_peek_string (param_values + 1),
                       g_marshal_value_peek_pointer (param_values + 2),
                       data2);

  g_value_set_boolean (return_value, v_return);
}

G_END_DECLS

#endif /* __dbus_glib_marshal_srv_MARSHAL_H__ */

#include <dbus/dbus-glib.h>
static const DBusGMethodInfo dbus_glib_srv_methods[] = {
  { (GCallback) srv_hallo, dbus_glib_marshal_srv_BOOLEAN__STRING_POINTER, 0 },
};

const DBusGObjectInfo dbus_glib_srv_object_info = {  1,
  dbus_glib_srv_methods,
  1,
"test.example\0Hallo\0S\0name\0I\0s\0\0\0",
"\0",
"\0"
};
```

The main:

```
#include <dbus/dbus-glib.h>

void srv_hallo(const char *name)
{
    g_print("Hallo %s\n", name);
}

#include "test_example_Server.h"



int main()
{
    /* Establish the mainloop */
    GMainLoop *mainloop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);

    /* Connect with the bus */
    GError *error = NULL;
    DBusGConnection *connection = dbus_g_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SESSION, &error);
    if (!connection) {
        g_critical("Couldn't connect to session bus: %s\n", error->message);
    }

    /* Create a proxy for the connection */
    DBusGProxy *proxy = dbus_g_proxy_new_for_name(connection,
                                      "org.freedesktop.DBus",
                                      "/org/freedesktop/DBus",
                                      "org.freedesktop.DBus");

    /* Request a name for the service from the bus */
    guint request_name_result;
    if(!dbus_g_proxy_call(proxy, "RequestName", &error,
                          G_TYPE_STRING, "test.example",
                          G_TYPE_UINT, 0,
                          G_TYPE_INVALID,
                          G_TYPE_UINT, &request_name_result,
                          G_TYPE_INVALID)) {
        g_critical("Couldn't acquire test.example: %s\n", error->message);
    }

    /* Create a new object */
    ToDo

    /* Register object on the server */
    ToDo

    g_main_loop_run(mainloop);    
}
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to include header file to the stub file:

```
#include "head_file.h"
```

It's only temporary solution but it works.